# Numpy Array of Strings Has Both Strings And Arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I created an array like this:
      `current_pop = np.full(N, "W", dtype = object)`
 and iterated over current_pop with for loop `for i in np.arange(0, len(current_pop)):`

when I `print(current_pop[i])` I mostly get "W" but occasionally ["W"] and it's screwing up my program.

Full code here:

```
#Table
populations_index = {
    'W' : 0,
    'A' : 0,
    'B' : 0,
    'C' : 0
}



#initialize our population of 100
N = 100
current_pop = np.full(N, "W", dtype = object)

#create our probabiliy vector
mutant_prob_dictionary = {
    "A" : 0.01, 
    "B" : 0.015,
    "C" : 0.018
}

trials = np.arange(0, 501, 1)


for t in trials:
    #every time I need to refresh prob and mutant list
    mutant_p = [mutant_prob_dictionary['A'], mutant_prob_dictionary['B'],mutant_prob_dictionary['C']]
    mutant = ['A','B','C']
    assert(len(mutant) == 3)

    #run through each cell
    for i in np.arange(0, len(current_pop)):

        #ERROR HERE:
        assert(type(current_pop[i]) == str)


        if current_pop[i][0] == "W":
            wild_prob = 1 - np.sum(mutant_p)
            mutant_p.append(wild_prob) #add wild prob at the end
            prob_vector = mutant_p

            mutant.append('W') #add wild self to end
            species_vector = mutant
            assert(np.sum(prob_vector) == 1)
        else: #must be mutant

            mutant_p.remove(mutant_prob_dictionary[current_pop[i][0]]) #remove its prob
            mutant.remove(current_pop[i][0]) #remove itself
            own_prob = 1 - np.sum(mutant_p)
            mutant_p.append(own_prob) #add its prob at the end
            mutant.append(current_pop[i][0]) #add itself at the end

            prob_vector = mutant_p
            species_vector = mutant

        #Now I have a probability vector and a species vector
        #draw a cell based off the mutation prob
        new_cell = np.random.choice(species_vector, size = 1, p = prob_vector)
        print(current_pop[i])

        current_pop[i] = new_cell

    for s in list(populations_index): #iterate for each species
        populations_index[s] = list(current_pop).count(s) #adds the population count of that species
```

Comment: Since you defined the array as `object` dtype, it's happy to accept both the character and the list.  If `dtype` was 'U3', you'd get an error at `current_pop[i] = new_cell` (assignment with a sequence).  With expressions like `current_pop[i][0]` it's unclear whether you want elements of `current_pop` to be lists or strings.  Finally, why are you using an array here?  why not a 'plain' list?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to *this line*

```
current_pop[i] = new_cell
```

Your variable `new_cell` is actually a list with one element: `['W']`.

You are assigning it to `current_pop`, which is meant to be a list of strings.

As soon as your inner loop finishes, i.e. `i` gets to `99`, the outer loop starts the second iteration and `i` goes back to being 0. But `current_pop[0]` is now `['W']` that you had set previously. Therefore, the error is raised.

To fix this, make sure you are assigning back a string to your `current_pop` list, e.g.

```
current_pop[i] = new_cell[0][0]
```